# Multiple variables in return object of function in R. Want to run it for multiple argument cases

Tags: r, return, apply, assign

How do I retrieve outputs from objects in an array as described in the background?

I have a function in R that returns multiple variables. For eg. if my function is called `function_ABC`,then:

```
 a<-function_ABC (input_var)
```

gives `a` such that `a$var1`, `a$var2`, and `a$var3` exist.

I have multiple cases to run such that I have put then in an array:

```
input_var <- c(1, 2, ...15)
```

for storing the outputs, I declared var such that:

```
var <- c(v1, v2, v3, .... v15)
```

Then I run:

```
assign(v1[i],function(input_var(i)))
```

However, after that I am unable to access these variables as `v1[1]$var1`. I can access them as: `v1$var1`, or `v3$var1`, etc. But this means I need to write 15*3 commands to retrieve my output.

Is there an easier way to do this?

Comment: Please provide a minimally reproducible example.

Comment: It is difficult to discern where exactly what your issue is. You don't give an example of your expected output, or any sample data you're coding with. I think both of these would be helpful when soliciting answers. I suspect you should be thoughtfully applying `lapply` here, but that's just a hunch at this point.

Comment: You can't store complex objects in a vector (using `c()`), you need a proper R `list()`. You should not really be using `assign()` with most normal R code. Again, you can store things in a named list to make it much easier to organize data. It's easier to help you if you include a simple [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input and desired output that can be used to test and verify possible solutions.

Answer (score 0):

1. Push your whole input set into an array Arr[ ].
2. Open a multi threaded executor E of certain size N.
3. Using a for loop on the input array Arr[], submit your function calls as a Callable job to the executor E. While submitting each job, hold the reference to the FutureTask in another Array FTArr[ ].
4. When all the FutureTask jobs are executed, you may retrieve the output for each of them by running another for loop on FTArr[ ].

Note :
• make sure to add synchronized block in your func_ABC, where you are accessing shared resources to avoid deadlocks.
• Please refer to the below link, if you want to know more about the usage of a count-down-latch. A count-down-latch helps you to find out, when exactly, all the child threads have finished execution.
https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/countdownlatch-in-java/